# How to script in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and call it from a batch file?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, script, uefi, grub2

Over on https://askubuntu.com/a/1108609/912537 I suggested a method to edit grub from windows. I have grub installed on /boot/efi/EFI/grub and have been trying to create a script which changes the "next_entry" variable in the Grub Environment Block.

Dual booting Win10 and Debian9, I have WSL running Debian (Bash on Win).

I am trying to use a script as a reboot to Linux shortcut since my BT keyboard doesn't work in GRUB. I have the reverse working from Linux just fine. I have a batch file and a shell script *(not)* working in tandem.  Here is the code:

**reboot-to-linux.bat**

```
@echo off
mountvol s: /S
wsl /mnt/c/Users/<username>/Documents/User_scripts/reboot-to-linux.sh
mountvol s: /D
Restart-Computer -Computername 'localhost'
```

**reboot-to-linux.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t drvfs s: /mnt/s
sudo grub-editenv /mnt/s/EFI/grub/grubenv set next_entry=0
sudo umount /mnt/s
```

*This is the error I'm getting:*

> does not existint /mnt/s
>
> grub-editenv: error: cannot open `/mnt/s/EFI/grub/grubenv.new': No such file or directory.
>
> umount: /mnt/s: not mounted

*Which tells me that the mount command is failing to mount the s: windows mountpoint onto /mnt/s - weirdly, each of these commands works individually in their respective consoles, I'm obviously not writing the scripts correctly.*

**What is the correct way to write these scripts?**

Answer (score 1):

In fact, both the scripts are functional however the batch commands can be wrapped by the line

```
@powershell -c " "
```

to be run from outside a terminal and as for the shell script - don't write your scripts in **notepad** people. Yes, a rookie mistake, Windows had made me complacent. FYI notepad and other windows editiors use "carriage return, line feed" as their new line (/r/n) and Linux expects just a line-feed (/n) so this breaks the script.

Also, better idea is to store your shell script in the wsl filesystem rather than somewhere in /mnt/c - just keep windows away from it. There you have it - clickable reboot shortcuts from Linux to windows and back again! I think I'll be seeing less and less of Windows these days.